# App activity crashes while updating SQLite database row and after flash previous activity opens

Tags: android, sqlite, flash, exception, android-sqlite

My first first activity inserts data and then  go to second activity
Second Activity updates the inserted row using **"A"** and go to third activity
NOW,....Third Activity activity updates the same row using **B**....But this activity just close after a flash and 2nd activity opens up again and log is showing nothing except PID with different number every time and **SIG:9** and this is same every time.......CODE of UPDATE and INSERT is here

```
        public boolean updateForm1(String fake,String Res, String Gen,String rooms){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues =new ContentValues();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if(Objects.equals(fake, "A")){
        contentValues.put(CoL_4,Res);
        contentValues.put(CoL_5,Gen);
        contentValues.put(CoL_6,rooms);
            db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, "Residence = ?",new String[] { fake });
            db.close();}
        else if(Objects.equals(fake, "B")){
            contentValues.put(CoL_7,Res);
            contentValues.put(CoL_8,Gen);
            db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, "Construction = ?",new String[] { fake });
            db.close();
        }
    }


    return true;
}

 public boolean insertData (String lat,String lng){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues =new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CoL_2,lat);
    contentValues.put(CoL_3,lng);
    contentValues.put(CoL_4,"A");
    contentValues.put(CoL_7,"B");
    long res =db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    db.close();
    return res != -1;



}
```

In Main Activity this function is inserting

```
       private void goToLocationZoom(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
}

Marker marker;


public void Tag(View view)  {

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);




    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(Double.toString(lat), Double.toString(lng));
    if (isInserted == true) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else
    {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    intent =new Intent (this,Form1Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);



}
```

Second Activityyyyyy is hereeeeee.......

```
     public class Form1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static RadioGroup radioGroup1,radioGroup2;
private static RadioButton Gr1Option,Gr2Option;
private static Button Enter;

DatabaseHelper myDbForm1;
private EditText Ed1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form1);
    Enter();
}
public void Enter(){
    myDbForm1 = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG1);
    radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG2);
    Enter= (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter1);

    Enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int selected1 =radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int selected2 =radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            Gr1Option= (RadioButton) findViewById(selected1);
            Gr2Option= (RadioButton) findViewById(selected2);
            Ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            if(Gr1Option== null || Gr2Option== null || Ed1==null )
            {
                Toast.makeText(Form1Activity.this,"Select one of the options", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                String a=Gr1Option.getText().toString();
                String b=Gr2Option.getText().toString();
                String c=Ed1.getText().toString();

                boolean isInserted = myDbForm1.updateForm1("A",a,b,c);
                if (isInserted) {
                    Toast.makeText(Form1Activity.this, "Data of form1 Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else
               {Toast.makeText(Form1Activity.this, "Data of form1 not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

                Toast.makeText(Form1Activity.this, Gr1Option.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(Form1Activity.this, Gr2Option.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(Form1Activity.this, Ed1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });


}

public void Next(View view){
    if(Gr1Option== null || Gr2Option== null|| Ed1==null )
    {
        Toast.makeText(Form1Activity.this,"Select one of the options and press Enter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Intent intent =new Intent(Form1Activity.this,Form2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

}

Third Activity which is updating row second time.............

```
  public class Form2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static RadioGroup radioGroup21,radioGroup22;
private static RadioButton Gr21Option,Gr22Option;
private static Button Enter2;

DatabaseHelper myDbForm2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form2);
    Enter2();
}

public void Enter2(){
    radioGroup21 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG21);
    radioGroup22 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG22);
    Enter2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter2);

    Enter2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int selected1 =radioGroup21.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int selected2 =radioGroup22.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            Gr21Option= (RadioButton) findViewById(selected1);
            Gr22Option= (RadioButton) findViewById(selected2);
            if(Gr21Option== null || Gr22Option== null )
            {
                Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this,"Select one of the options", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {

                String a1=Gr21Option.getText().toString();
                String b1=Gr22Option.getText().toString();
                boolean isInserted = myDbForm2.updateForm1("B",a1,b1,"1");
                if (isInserted) {
                    Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this, "Data of form2 Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else
                {Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this, "Data of form2 not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this, Gr21Option.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this, Gr22Option.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: If app crashes, there must be a log entry. If not, there must be something in your Activity's code that closes the respective Activity.

Comment: that is the thing.......app is not crashing

Comment: it flashes and opens the previous activity...........and i told earlier the log message SIG:9 comes every time

Comment: Please post the code for the Activity class in question

Comment: how to update this question>?..Kindly guide me

Comment: Just below the question, you will find three buttons or links in the left hand side "share", "edit" and "flag" respectively. Click on edit and make the changes required to your question and save it. The option to save is in the bottom of the respective webpage.

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: @RujulGandhi  **PID:"with different numbers every time"**  and **SIG:9**

Comment: Why are you trying to update the row second time?

Comment: @VarunKumar  I want to add data in one row...App has 8 activities each activity should insert data in few columns of that same row

Comment: When first activity inserts data reamining columns are null@VarunKumar

Comment: When does 3rd Activity return back to 2nd? Automatically or when you perform any action?

Comment: When **enter** is used

Comment: Where have you declared "Enter2" as a `Button` in 3rd `Activity`?

Comment: Enter2() function

Comment: @VarunKumar button declared in start of class

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that one.

Comment: Are all the `Toast` inside the `IF` blocks working properly?

Comment: yes they are working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  function is working for me now

```
          public void Enter2(){


 myDbForm2 = new DatabaseHelper(this);
radioGroup21 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG21);
radioGroup22 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG22);
Enter2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter2);

Enter2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int selected1 =radioGroup21.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        int selected2 =radioGroup22.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        Gr21Option= (RadioButton) findViewById(selected1);
        Gr22Option= (RadioButton) findViewById(selected2);
        if(Gr21Option== null || Gr22Option== null )
        {
            Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this,"Select one of the options", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {

            String a1=Gr21Option.getText().toString();
            String b1=Gr22Option.getText().toString();
            boolean isInserted = myDbForm2.updateForm1("B",a1,b1,"1");
            if (isInserted) {
                Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this, "Data of form2 Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else
            {Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this, "Data of form2 not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this, Gr21Option.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(Form2Activity.this, Gr22Option.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised "myDbForm2" in third `Activity`

Comment: **DatabaseHelper myDbForm2;**

Comment: i tried this method but one guy suggested to use update instead

Comment: I'm saying that you have used the object without initialising it